# Export Multi-factor ANOVA [TRAMINER] to latex

Tags: r, sequences, anova, traminer

I try to export the result of a multi factor analysis of sequences in latex table form. I tried to do with `xtable()` but R says that it ## Heading ## cannot do it with this feature ... Someone would have an idea ?

```
XXX.mfac <- dissmfacw(XXX.dist ~ variable1 + variable2 + variable3, data = XXX, R = 1000)
print(XXX.mfac)
xtable(XXX.mfac)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you want to print is located in the element "mfac". Thus, you can use:

```
xtable(XXX.mfac$mfac)
print(xtable(XXX.mfac$mfac), include.rownames=F)
```

Hope this helps.